# implementing 301-redirect in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I want to do a 301-redirect from my old php-URL to the new URL in my htaccess-file:

redirecting

```
https://www.example.com/subpage/location-1.php
https://www.example.com/locations/locations/location-2.php
https://www.example.com/locations/locations/location-3.php
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/subpage/location-1
https://www.example.com/subpage/location-2
https://www.example.com/subpage/location-3
```

I have a htaccess-code and tried following htaccess-code:

```
# redirect php-version to location page
RewriteRule ^subpage/location-1.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^locations/locations/location-2.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^locations/locations/location-3.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-3 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Can someone help and correct me? I am not that familiar with htaccess.

Here is the entire htaccess-code:

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
    # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
    <files .htaccess>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.html>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.txt>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files wp-config.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>

    # Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
    Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/install\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
        RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule (^|.*/)\.(git|svn)/.* - [F]

        # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Uploads
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]

        # Disable PHP in Plugins - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Plugins
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/plugins/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]

        # Disable PHP in Themes - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Themes
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/themes/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]
    </IfModule>
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE



# redirect "/subpage/" & "/subpage2/" to root (and HTTPS / www)
RewriteRule ^subpage/$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^subpage2/$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]


# redirect php-version to location page
RewriteRule ^subpage/location-1.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^locations/locations/location-2.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^locations/locations/location-3.php https://www.example.com/subpage/location-3 [R=301,L]



# redirect to HTTPS & www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The directives you've posted and the location you've put them in look OK, except they don't quite match the example URLs you posted earlier... you've used `location-1` again in the second rule and you've appended a trailing slash to the target? Also make sure you've cleared your browser cache and test first with 302s.

Comment: @MrWhite thank you very much. It works well now.
There was a typo, I corrected the second rule to `location-2`.
And I also removed the trailing slash.
I tested first with 302, then changed it to 301.